# Branching tree with tight continuous relaxation

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, integer-programming

Suppose you are solving an integer, linear math problem. The continuous relaxation is denoted by $z$, and the optimal solution is denoted by $z^*$.

In a branch-and-bound algorithm, is it possible to have more than one node in the branching tree if the continuous relaxation is tight, i.e., if $z^*=z$ ?

Comment: Do you mean whether the root node can assume the optimal value while the solution is not integral?

Comment: Yes that would be another way of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. If you solve $\max_{x \in \{0,1\}^2}\{ x_1+x_2 : x_1+x_2\leq 1 \}$ with an interior point solver, the root node will have $x=(0.5, 0.5)$ and you need to branch.

Comment: Great! But you mean max I think in the objective function otherwise, the solution is $(0,0)$. Or equivalently, $\ge$ instead of $\le$ in the constraint. Am i right?

Comment: Right, thanks! You can easily construct more examples by taking a constant objective function.

Comment: Good point. But is this possible with a solver that does not use interior points? The example in the answer clearly does not work with the simplex.

Comment: I think this would happen even with the simplex algorithm with $\max_{x \in \{0,1\}^2}\{ x_1+x_2 : x_1+x_2\leq 1, x_2\ge x_1 \}$, as $(0.5,0.5)$ is now a vertex of the polygon.

Comment: With the simplex method you may be "lucky" to end up with an integer solution.

Comment: In practice, I think you would use cross-over strategies to avoid these non-vertex solutions.